# How to determine what item of listbox is selected in wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython

I am making a music player. I have a listbox that contains a list of the songs from the directory "songs". How do I determine which song is selected and how would I go about playing it?

CODE:

```
    songlist = os.listdir('songs')
    self.myListBox = listbox = wx.ListBox(panel2, -1, (10,200), (140,200), songlist, wx.LB_SINGLE)

    self.Bind(wx.EVT_LIST_ITEM_SELECTED, self.selLoadFile, listbox)

def selLoadFile(self, event):
    file_path = os.path.join(os.os.getcwd(), "songs", self.myListBox.getSelectedItem())
    self.doLoadFile(file_path)

   ########### I believe the problem is above ^ here. But I could be wrong. 

def Load(self, event):
    dlg = wx.FileDialog(self, "Choose a media file", "songs", "", "*.*", wx.OPEN)
    if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
        path = dlg.GetPath()
        self.doLoadFile(path)
        dlg.Destroy() 

def doLoadFile(self, path):
    if not self.mc.Load(path):
        wx.MessageBox("Unable to load %s: Unsupported format?" % path, "ERROR", wx.ICON_ERROR | wx.OK)

    else:
        folder, filename = os.path.split(path)
        self.st_file.SetLabel('%s' % filename)
        self.mc.SetBestFittingSize()
        self.mc.Play()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple issues. First of all you have the wrong event bound. The EVT_LIST_ITEM_SELECTED is for the wx.ListCtrl. You want EVT_LISTBOX. Next in your handler you have getSelectedItem, which isn't a real method. There is GetSelection which returns the integer position of the item that is selected (0-based) and there is GetStringSelection(), which is probably what you want.

You don't say what you're using for playback. Are you using wx.media.MediaCtrl? If so, then this tutorial I wrote on playing MP3s may help you: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/04/20/wxpython-creating-a-simple-mp3-player/

I have also played with the MplayerCtrl which wraps Mplayer and seems more robust than the MediaCtrl, although it can be a little complicated to set up. You can read about it here if you like: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/07/24/wxpython-creating-a-simple-media-player/

Comment: Thanks for the info! And that is a great tutorial and example, that is what I used to help build my music player in the first place. Oh and I am using wx.media.MediaCtrl